# Why can't a contract wake up and run itself?

Tags: contract-design, timers, scheduling

This question is not about [external solutions](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/42/42), but are there technical limitations to why a contract that has funds, can't schedule itself to run at a future block?  Could the Ethereum protocol have been designed to include this functionality and if so, what would it have involved?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a recent [post](https://www.reddit.com/r/ethereum/comments/m4ftnv/some_technical_proposals_that_were_considered_for/) by Vitalik Buterin on Reddit he mentions several proposals that were considered in the protocol design but didn't make the cut.

One of the proposals called *delayed calls* would introduce an opcode ALARM that allow a contract to execute in a future block. The proposal has several use cases but it was discarded due to time constraints.

Answer (score 7):

I believe this was designed as a feature to minimize the burden on the network and reduce resources.  There are several solutions if you want to "call on a contract":

http://www.ethereum-alarm-clock.com/

[Source](https://forum.ethereum.org/discussion/3571/ethereum-alarm-clock-call-scheduling-for-contracts):

> I'm proud to announce the launch of the Ethereum Alarm Clock service.
>
> http://www.ethereum-alarm-clock.com/
>
> The Alarm service facilitates scheduling contract function calls for a specified block number in the future. The current release should be considered alpha software.
>
> - Schedule contract function calls to be executed at a specified block in the future.
> - Trustless. No administrative API's or special access granted to anyone, including myself.
> - Published verifiable source code.
> - Lots of documentation with examples.
>
> I'm very interested to hear people's feedback. Feel free to send me a message at pipermerriam on gitter.

Comment: You mention "several" solutions?

Comment: If the technical limitation is network and resource usage would increase, can it be explained or quantified better to illustrate why it actually becomes a limitation?  An increase in something doesn't necessarily mean it becomes a limitation.

Comment: Just wondering... For a contract function to be called, a transaction has to be written to the blockchain, since a function is executed when that transaction is mined and verified. So perhaps one way to implement this could be to use Events. (Just an idea). A function in a smart contract could subscribe to an Event. When that Event is triggered, transactions could be sent to the blockchain calling each function subscribed to that event - one transaction for each subscribed function. Still, it depends on an event being triggered. Not completely self-invoked.

Comment: I have another idea about implementing this functionality but this might not be the right forum for it. Will look for some place where it would get a serious consideration by the powers-that-be. Perhaps, something like this is already in the works. Will check that, too.