# Is it possible to do something on a specific block number?

Tags: solidity, transactions

Is it possible to do something on a specific block number? (e.g. publish a contract or execute a transaction)

Comment: This is a related question to http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/304/1366 but not an exact duplicate. It may be helpful for people who do not think of this behavior as "waking up."

Comment: Yes, I upvoted your question.  Main benefit of duplicate is trying to group answers together: there's basically 2 questions: ["why it isn't possible"](http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/304/why-cant-a-contract-wake-up-and-run-itself) and ["workarounds"](http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/42/how-can-a-contract-run-itself-at-a-later-time).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Transactions are not guaranteed to happen on the next block or any future specific block, since it is up to the miners to include transactions and not up to the submitter of the transaction. This applies to function calls/transactions and contract creation transactions.
>
> If you want to schedule future calls of your contract, you can use the [Ethereum alarm clock](http://www.ethereum-alarm-clock.com/).

Retrieved from: http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/latest/frequently-asked-questions.html