# What happens when you put an recursive schedule call with Ethereum Alarm Clock scheduler?

Tags: contract-design, timers, scheduling

My goal is to schedule a call once every day.

[Q] Is it possible to use recursive function to schedule a call once every day using Ethereum Alarm Clock scheduler?

Example from following answer https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/87/4575 :

> ```
> contract SchedulerAPI { 
>     function scheduleCall(address contractAddress,
>                           bytes4 abiSignature,
>                           uint targetBlock) public returns (address); }
>
> contract CallMeLater {
>     // The address of the v0.6.0 Alarm Clock scheduler contract.
>     address constant Scheduler = SchedulerAPI(0xe109ecb193841af9da3110c80fdd365d1c23be2a);
>
>     function CallMeLater() {
>         // Schedule a call to the `callback` function
>         Scheduler.value(2 ether).scheduleCall(
>             address(this),               // the address that should be called.
>             bytes4(sha3("callback()")),  // 4-byte abi signature of callback fn
>             block.number + 5082,          // the block number to execute the call 
>         );               //As we know 1 day duration (1440 minutes): 5082 blocks.
>     }
>
>     function callback() public {
>         // whatever code you want executed.
>           CallMeLater(); //added: recursive call.
>     } }
> ```

I added additional `CallMeLater();` into end of `callback()` function, I assume, which will make new schedule (1 day ahead) in order to call `callback()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Solution**

The protocol changed since the question was posted. It is possible to do recursive calls by building a service that for example takes advantage of Proxy wallet (to fund following calls).

[Ethereum Alarm Clock has RecurringPayment example in its repository.](https://github.com/ethereum-alarm-clock/ethereum-alarm-clock/blob/master/contracts/_examples/RecurringPayment.sol) This is the contract:

```
pragma solidity 0.4.24;

import "contracts/Interface/SchedulerInterface.sol";

/// Example of using the Scheduler from a smart contract to delay a payment.
contract RecurringPayment {
    SchedulerInterface public scheduler;

    uint paymentInterval;
    uint paymentValue;
    uint lockedUntil;

    address recipient;
    address public currentScheduledTransaction;

    event PaymentScheduled(address indexed scheduledTransaction, address recipient, uint value);
    event PaymentExecuted(address indexed scheduledTransaction, address recipient, uint value);

    function RecurringPayment(
        address _scheduler,
        uint _paymentInterval,
        uint _paymentValue,
        address _recipient
    )  public payable {
        scheduler = SchedulerInterface(_scheduler);
        paymentInterval = _paymentInterval;
        recipient = _recipient;
        paymentValue = _paymentValue;

        schedule();
    }

    function ()
        public payable 
    {
        if (msg.value > 0) { //this handles recieving remaining funds sent while scheduling (0.1 ether)
            return;
        } 

        process();
    }

    function process() public returns (bool) {
        payout();
        schedule();
    }

    function payout()
        private returns (bool)
    {
        require(block.number >= lockedUntil);
        require(address(this).balance >= paymentValue);

        recipient.transfer(paymentValue);

        emit PaymentExecuted(currentScheduledTransaction, recipient, paymentValue);
        return true;
    }

    function schedule() 
        private returns (bool)
    {
        lockedUntil = block.number + paymentInterval;

        currentScheduledTransaction = scheduler.schedule.value(0.1 ether)( // 0.1 ether is to pay for gas, bounty and fee
            this,                   // send to self
            "",                     // and trigger fallback function
            [
                1000000,            // The amount of gas to be sent with the transaction. Accounts for payout + new contract deployment
                0,                  // The amount of wei to be sent.
                255,                // The size of the execution window.
                lockedUntil,        // The start of the execution window.
                20000000000 wei,    // The gasprice for the transaction (aka 20 gwei)
                20000000000 wei,    // The fee included in the transaction.
                20000000000 wei,         // The bounty that awards the executor of the transaction.
                30000000000 wei     // The required amount of wei the claimer must send as deposit.
            ]
        );

        emit PaymentScheduled(currentScheduledTransaction, recipient, paymentValue);
    }
}
```

Basically you can see that constructor function is `payable`, that means you have to fund the contract when creating it. This will fund future recursive calls.

Good example to look at is also [Recurring Alarm Clock](https://github.com/everchain-project/recurring-alarm-clock). The project is open-source and you can take a look at the code.

**Misinformation in other answers/comments**

Well, the other answer doesn't take into account how Ethereum Alarm Clock works - that call is scheduled, not instantly called. This means, there won't be infinite loop, it's more like `setInterval` in JavaScript.

Someone also misinforms in comment that there's `gracePeriod`, which would mean: "You'll find a parameter "gracePeriod" which says you cannot make the same call after 255 blocks." - but this is also wrong.

The linked documentation itself is outdated, but it says:

> uint8 gracePeriod: The number of blocks after targetBlock that it is
>   ok to still execute this call. Cannot be less than 64. (default:
>   255).

So gracePeriod in this example can be read as EXECUTION WINDOW.

Answer (score 1):

Gas assumption issue might be there?
I guesstimate as long as "this function capable accepting fund for Gas", this scheduled contract would run forever.

Comment: @alpher Were you able to verify this?

Comment: According to [this](https://ethereum-alarm-clock-service.readthedocs.io/en/v0.6.0/scheduling.html#scheduling-the-call) document. You'll find a parameter "gracePeriod" which says you cannot make the same call after 255 blocks. So doesn't it mean that there is a limit in recursive?