# Unable to schedule a call using Aion Recurring Contract

Tags: solidity, contract-development, contract-invocation, timestamp

So here's the contract that I deployed on Ropsten Network. I took code refer from [here](https://github.com/ETH-Pantheon/Aion#3-recurrent-calls).

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.24;


// interface Aion 
contract Aion { 
    uint256 public serviceFee;
    function ScheduleCall(uint256 blocknumber, address to, uint256 value, uint256 gaslimit, uint256 gasprice, bytes data, bool schedType) public payable returns (uint,address);
}

// Main contract
contract MyContract{
uint256 public sqrtValue;
Aion aion;
uint256 public myData;

constructor(uint256 number) public payable{
    scheduleMyfucntion(number);
    myData = 1;
}

function scheduleMyfucntion(uint256 number) public {
    aion = Aion(0xFcFB45679539667f7ed55FA59A15c8Cad73d9a4E);
    bytes memory data = abi.encodeWithSelector(bytes4(keccak256('myfucntion(uint256)')),number); 
    uint callCost = 200000*1e9 + aion.serviceFee();
    aion.ScheduleCall.value(callCost)( block.timestamp + 10 minutes, address(this), 0, 200000, 1e9, data, true);
}

function myfucntion(uint256 number) public {
    // do your task here and call again the function to schedule
    myData = myData+1;
    scheduleMyfucntion(number);
} 

function getMyData() view public returns (uint256) {
    return myData;
}
function () public payable {}
}
```

The purpose of this contract is to schedule a call in every 10 minutes.

**Expectations:** myData variable should be incremented by one in every 10 minutes.

**Actual:** Unable to see any new transaction after successful deployment. Nor able to see the variable being incremented ever.

Comment: Can you please share the address of your deployed contract?

Comment: Yes. I have redeployed the contract. Here's the address: 0x157b9c5fc098a3Ae144E32f5EB3498FfC0063635

Comment: Umm. It's strange but this newly deployed contract is working. :/ I did nothing but re-deployed it.

Comment: Here's the list of contract addresses which didn't work till now.! 0x778a8a3d4fe72be32e2d6e95d07e5b1799c17069,
0xba034f3ae444bab679c252c83af7f558974872b6, 0x4409453f0a3ec2acce8d9e7ed6296024f5c9991e, 0x1bc58aea415db508aba290ea275a226c48c54861.

Comment: Yes, I also deploy a new one [here]( https://ropsten.etherscan.io/address/0xd9fb8ff62961b35509dd1d119e4f92e1fa1f003b) and it works. It may have been some issue with Aions testnet server but the transactions should be picked up if they were not cancelled.

Comment: still running for me, seems this was solved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I deployed the contract and it seems to work well. The only explanation could be that the server of the test network missed your request.

Also, your code uses a variable named `number`. I went through the link you posted and this seems to be only to show that you can send data together with your request, you are safe to remove that variable.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks! I implemented this to my real project and deployed it successfully. First time it runs well but when it is called by Aion contract at the scheduled time later it reverts. Here's the [Txn hash](https://ropsten.etherscan.io/tx/0x306c79816fd4c8f96ea7b9f4e19356db02387e4c7fc5ee77be1ea8054d2245fe) which failed. Any thought? :(

Comment: I see that the schedule was executed and an attempt to reschedule fail. Checking the smart contract of Aion the only possibility that the request fails is that you do not send the correct amount of ether to pay for the transactions. Can you please share the code of your real project?.

Comment: Did you solve this?

Comment: Yes @Jaime thanks! I solved this. I made my function payable but never sent ethers to it when rescheduling happens.