# How to schedule a transaction?

Tags: go-ethereum, transactions, parity, dapp-development, scheduling

Anyone can guide me on how to schedule a transaction to be sent once a specific block number is mined?

Thanks

Comment: Related: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/42/how-can-a-contract-run-itself-at-a-later-time

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You could run the following function :

```
function f( blocknumber, to_address,   value_) {


  var filter = web3.eth.filter('latest').watch(function(err, blockHash) {

  var target=blocknumber;
  if(web3.eth.blockNumber==target)
  {
      filter.stopWatching();
      //your function here
      web3.eth.sendTransaction({to:to_address, from:web3.eth.coinbase,  value: web3.toWei(value_,"ether")});

      filter = null;
      console.warn('Block reached');
      if (callback)
        return callback(false);
      else
        return false;
    }

      else {
      console.log('Waiting the block');

    }
  });
};
```

I've tried it in geth (while i don't use parity) and it works perfectly. be careful with the synchronous methods `eth_blockNumber`.

Comment: I'll switch to geth as well, I thought this was something feasible from the Parity UI that's why I asked. Thanks

Answer (score 11):

Just schedule it with the wallet user interface.

[image: accounts transaction 1]

Create any transaction you like, make sure you select "advanced settings" and determine the condition to be either:

- send after block number
- send after date and time

Parity will hold this transaction back until the condition is met. Note, for this your node needs to keep running.

Comment: Great! Will I be able to sign the transaction before scheduling it or will it prompt me to do so when the block height is reached?

Comment: You will sing it immediately, but it withholds the transaction from broadcasting until the time or block condition is met.

Answer (score 4):

If your question is about how to send a transaction *yourself* at any point after a certain block height is reached, then you can run an ever-running daemon on a host you control, that will do it in a programmatic way – like the answer from @BadrBelaj.

If on the other hand what you want is to send a transaction to the network now and have it executed *automatically by the network* once at a certain block height, then **you can't do it natively** at Ethereum level. However, there are neat deployed smart contracts such as [the Ethereum Alarm Clock](http://www.ethereum-alarm-clock.com/), that rely on the crowd to do the work "the Ethereum way". It's very clever and maybe it will solve your use case.

Comment: Yes, Badr's answer is exactly what I need. The second option doesn't seem optimal to me as it's not really automatic.

Answer (score 0):

It's quite easy to do using [Ethereum Alarm Clock](http://www.ethereum-alarm-clock.com/), which has been deployed to mainnet and since then working perfectly. 100% transactions have been executed so far.

You can schedule a transaction for specific block/time using following ways:

1. Use [MyCrypto](https://mycrypto.com) (toggle "Send Later" button) - [here's helpful tutorial](https://medium.com/@MyCrypto/schedule-your-ethereum-transactions-now-on-mycrypto-92a6305f7dcc).

[image: MyCrypto interface for scheduling]

2. Use [Ethereum Alarm Clock DAPP](https://app.chronologic.network)

Both ways are equally good.

About the protocol itself - it has been security audited. There was more than 1000 ETH already moved through the protocol.

---

[Ethereum Alarm Clock](http://www.ethereum-alarm-clock.com/) is decentralized and automatic. It's currently the best way to schedule a transaction and is not subject to problems that solutions posted in other answers are.

*Addressing other answers:*

*Someone here mentioned that EAC way is not the best, because "it's not automatic". Well, just to say - **it is fully automatic**. Other answer mentions using local client to schedule transaction - it's centralized way, subject to power and internet shortages, as well as to software bugs. You also need to run your computer round the clock for this work.*