# What is the fastest way to call a function for incoming ICO

Tags: solidity, ico, alarm

We have Alarm Contract: http://docs.ethereum-alarm-clock.com/en/latest/

We have parity client-side scheduling: [Parity - How to schedule a transaction?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/16464/parity-how-to-schedule-a-transaction)

We can write custom contracts similar to [this contract](https://etherscan.io/address/0x6bd33d49d48f76abcd96652e5347e398aa3fda96#code). [Reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/ethereum/comments/6ghqp0/never_miss_an_ico_again/)

According to my test results, parity client side scheduling is not the best and guaranteed way to be the first one in. Plus, you have to run the node all the time.
So, what would the fastest way to get into ICO based on ERC20?