# Automated execution of smart contract

Tags: solidity, contract-development, contract-deployment

What are the chances to create such a smart contract whose function is executed automatically at certain point of time (timestamp) ?
         I actually mean that i can write some functions of smart contract and this contract can have a functionality that once it is deployed to the network, i can stop my node but the one particular function of smart contract is executed. 
Please let me know if more explanation is needed. Thanks !

**EDIT 1 :**

My question is different from [How can a contract run itself at a later time?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/42/how-can-a-contract-run-itself-at-a-later-time)
question , i am aware about ethereum-alarm-clock and Answer in given link states `"For the service to operate, it requires people to initiate the transactions that execute scheduled calls."` I just want it completely automated. In case of any confusion or suggestion, leave a comment

Comment: the second part of your question isn't clear for me:  i can stop my node but the one particular function of smart contract is executed.

Comment: I just want that when my node is running, i can set a time for a smart contract function execution, this logic can be in smart contract itself. And once time is set , i can close my node still contract function is executed. Is it clear now?

Comment: @RichardHorrocks Thanks for the comment. Answer in your link states `"For the service to operate, it requires people to initiate the transactions that execute scheduled calls."` I just want it completely automated. Please let me know your further queries.

Comment: Hi there. As per the answer in that duplicate question, and as stated below, what you're trying to do isn't strictly possible. I think the question I linked to already covers what you're asking :-)

Comment: @RichardHorrocks That's what i wanted to know...chances to do that. Thanks for the confirmation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. Completely automated execution of a contract function is not possible.

If you wanted to you could pre-sign a transaction that calls that function, and then setup a web based service (cron?) to submit the transaction to the chain at an appropriate time.

But 100% automated.. no. Impossible.

Comment: Ok, if in future you find something, that can make it possible, i will be happy to know. Thanks for the answer.