# Push Transfer of minted tokens

Tags: solidity, contract-development, contract-design, remix, architecture

How can I create a single function which on its own, will reward an address with minted tokens if a certain time condition is met? Every time I try, I can only get it to work if I create two functions and use pull pattern; to pull out the minted tokens to the subject address of my choice.

Comment: Share your code here.

Comment: Always favour pull over push mechanism

Comment: Does [this post](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/42/how-can-a-contract-run-itself-at-a-later-time) help?

Comment: do you want the function to reward the minted tokens *when* the time condition is met (possible only with pull), or reward it *if* the time condition is satisfied at the time of sending? (you don't need a pull in this case).

Comment: @shaish, Imagine a time-based lending contract where users are able to lend tokens to the contract and get back the same initial lended amount + an interest rate after x days. I want this payback action to be pushed back to the user without requiring the user to pull it by calling additional functionality..