# I want to write Time based Trigged Method in Solidity

Tags: solidity

I want to write Time based Triggered Method in Solidity.  Suppose I want to transfer toke after a certain time interval. It should trigger time once that time occurred.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

This is possible, but not within Ethereum. You can use external services like Aion (aion.ethpantheon.com). This service allows you to schedule any kind of transactions. You can test it on Ropsten and in their GitHub page you have code examples ready to work.

There are other services, ( [see this answer]([How to execute a time based transaction? Here's my sample contract](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/58377/32978) for a description of services with pros and cons)

Hope this help