# How to set time based function in solidity?

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, truffle, remix, keyword

I want to run a function after every 365 days in Solidity. I have tried to use the `now` keyword, but it is not working (I tried in Remix).

How can I get the time?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to execute a time based transaction? Here's my sample contract](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/58377/how-to-execute-a-time-based-transaction-heres-my-sample-contract)

Answer (score 0):

You can use any of the built-in [Solidity time units](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.7.3/units-and-global-variables.html#time-units).

For example, you can do:

```
function f(uint start) public {
    if (block.timestamp >= start + 365 days) {
      // ...
    }
}
```