# (Truffle) how to call finalize() function after finishing crowdsale

Tags: truffle, tokens, crowdsale, openzeppelin-contracts

I would like to call `token.transferOwnership(msg.sender)` after finishing timed crowdsale. So, I inherited FinalizableCrowdsale contract, then override `finalization()` function to call `transferOwnership` on the crowdsale contract.

Actually, I can test to call `crowdsale.finalize()` on Truffle console and it is working well, but I don't know how to call the function **automatically after finishing crowdsale**. When crowdsale started, the token ownership has been transferred to crowdsale contract. Um, Do I have to modify `hasClosed()` function in `TimedCrowdsale`? or is there any way to call the fucntion...?

I tried to call it on Etherscan after verifying the code, but I couldn't do cos the crowdsale contract has the ownership...

**Crowdsale Migration.js**

```
const DappToken = artifacts.require("./DappToken.sol");
const DappTokenCrowdsale = artifacts.require('DappTokenCrowdsale');

const ether = (n) => new web3.BigNumber(web3.toWei(n, 'ether'));

const duration = {
    seconds: function (val) { return val; },
    minutes: function (val) { return val * this.seconds(60); },
    hours: function (val) { return val * this.minutes(60); },
    days: function (val) { return val * this.hours(24); },
    weeks: function (val) { return val * this.days(7); },
    years: function (val) { return val * this.days(365); },
  };

// module.exports = function(deployer, network, accounts) {
module.exports = function(deployer, network, accounts) {
    const latestTime = Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000);
    const _token = DappToken.address;
    const _rate = 1000;

    const _wallet = accounts[3]; // Collecting Wallet
    const _openingTime = latestTime + duration.minutes(1);
    const _closingTime = _openingTime + duration.minutes(2);
    const _cap = ether(100);

    console.log("Open: " + new Date(_openingTime*1000) + " Close: " + new Date(_closingTime*1000));

    return deployer.deploy(DappTokenCrowdsale, _rate, _wallet, _token, _cap, _openingTime, _closingTime)
        .then(() => {
            return DappToken.deployed().then((token) => {
                return token.transferOwnership(DappTokenCrowdsale.address)
            });
        });
};
```

**Crowdsale Contract.sol**

```
pragma solidity 0.4.24;

import "./DappToken.sol";

import "../node_modules/openzeppelin-solidity/contracts/crowdsale/Crowdsale.sol";
import "../node_modules/openzeppelin-solidity/contracts/crowdsale/emission/MintedCrowdsale.sol";
import "../node_modules/openzeppelin-solidity/contracts/crowdsale/validation/CappedCrowdsale.sol";
import "../node_modules/openzeppelin-solidity/contracts/crowdsale/validation/TimedCrowdsale.sol";
import "../node_modules/openzeppelin-solidity/contracts/crowdsale/distribution/FinalizableCrowdsale.sol";
// import "../node_modules/openzeppelin-solidity/contracts/crowdsale/validation/WhitelistedCrowdsale.sol";

contract DappTokenCrowdsale is Crowdsale, MintedCrowdsale, CappedCrowdsale, TimedCrowdsale, FinalizableCrowdsale {
    MintableToken public token;
    address public tokenAddress;
    address public crowdsaleOwner;
    address public founderWallet;

    bool public isFinalized = false;

    constructor(
      uint256 _rate,
      address _wallet,
      MintableToken _token,
      uint256 _cap,
      uint256 _openingTime,
      uint256 _closingTime
    )
    Crowdsale(_rate, _wallet, _token)
    CappedCrowdsale(_cap)
    TimedCrowdsale(_openingTime, _closingTime)
    FinalizableCrowdsale()
    MintedCrowdsale()
    public
    {
      founderWallet = _wallet;
      token = _token;          
    }

    function finalization() internal {
      token.transferOwnership(msg.sender);
      super.finalization();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> automatically after finishing crowdsale

it is not possible to execute smart contract function automatically literally

in order to call `finalize` function after some period of time you can:

- call the function manually
- create any type of scheduled tasks/jobs which will execute the function
- [How can a contract run itself at a later time?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/42/how-can-a-contract-run-itself-at-a-later-time)

Answer (score 0):

Add the following function:

```
function finalizeIfNeeded () internal {
    if (!finalized && block.timestamp >= crowdsaleEndTime) {
        finalization ();
        finalized = true;
    }
}
```

and call it at the beginning of all your non-constant public functions whose behavior depend on whether crowd sale is finalized or not.

If you have some constant (e.g. `view`) functions whose behavior also depends on finalize status, add the following function:

```
function isFinalized () view returns (bool) {
    return finalized || block.timestamp >= crowdsaleEndTime;
}
```

and use it in your constant function to check whether crowd sale is finalized.