# Automate Chainlink Get API

Tags: solidity, chainlink, oracles, insurance, automate

I am working on a Parametric Insurance contract, the API call is working as expected, but I need to automate the call to the requestRainData() function. I need to constantly check if the rain MM in a certain location has passed a rain MM threshold (e.g. The threshold is 4 MM, when the API call returns 4 or more MM, then a payout should be done).

This is the code for calling the API:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT

pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

import "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.8/ChainlinkClient.sol";

contract WeatherConsumer is ChainlinkClient {
    using Chainlink for Chainlink.Request;

    address public owner;
    uint256 public rain;
    bytes32 private jobId;
    uint256 private fee;
    string constant WEATHERBIT_PATH = "data,0,precip";
    string constant API_URL =
        "https://api.weatherbit.io/v2.0/current?lat=8.503800&lon=-75.509070&key={My_Api_Key}";

    event RequestRain(bytes32 indexed requestId, uint256 rain);

    modifier onlyOwner() {
        require(
            owner == msg.sender,
            "Only the address that deployed the contract."
        );
        _;
    }

    // Spolia testnet
    constructor() {
        setChainlinkToken(0x779877A7B0D9E8603169DdbD7836e478b4624789);
        setChainlinkOracle(0x6090149792dAAeE9D1D568c9f9a6F6B46AA29eFD);
        jobId = "ca98366cc7314957b8c012c72f05aeeb";
        fee = (1 * LINK_DIVISIBILITY) / 10;
        owner = msg.sender;
    }

    function requestRainData() public returns (bytes32 requestId) {
        Chainlink.Request memory req = buildChainlinkRequest(
            jobId,
            address(this),
            this.fulfill.selector
        );

        req.add("get", API_URL);
        req.add("path", WEATHERBIT_PATH);

        int256 timesAmount = 10**18;
        req.addInt("times", timesAmount);

        return sendChainlinkRequest(req, fee);
    }

    function fulfill(bytes32 _requestId, uint256 _rain)
        public
        recordChainlinkFulfillment(_requestId)
    {
        emit RequestRain(_requestId, _rain);
        rain = _rain;
    }

    function withdrawLink() public onlyOwner {
        LinkTokenInterface link = LinkTokenInterface(chainlinkTokenAddress());
        require(
            link.transfer(msg.sender, link.balanceOf(address(this))),
            "Unable to transfer"
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Either you employ an external service (like this https://chain.link/automation) or make a script or cron job that simply calls the function.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can a contract run itself at a later time?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/42/how-can-a-contract-run-itself-at-a-later-time)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Chainlink Automation](https://docs.chain.link/chainlink-automation/introduction)'s Custom Upkeep functionality. Here's the pseudo code of potential implementation.

```js
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT

pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

import "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.8/AutomationCompatible.sol";
import "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.8/ChainlinkClient.sol";

contract WeatherConsumer is ChainlinkClient, AutomationCompatible {
    uint256 public rain;
    
    // if upkeepNeeded is true, performUpkeep will be called automatically, otherwise it won't
    function checkUpkeep(bytes calldata /* checkData */)
        external
        view
        override
        returns (bool upkeepNeeded, bytes memory /* performData */)
    {
        upkeepNeeded = rain > 4 MM;
        requestRainData(); // for the next check
    }

    function performUpkeep(bytes calldata /* performData */) external override {
        //We highly recommend revalidating the upkeep in the performUpkeep function
        require(rain > 4 MM);
        payout();
    }
}
```

After deploying an Automation Compatible contract, follow [these steps](https://docs.chain.link/chainlink-automation/register-upkeep) to register your upkeep using [Subscription Management UI](https://automation.chain.link/).